# android поиск решения

Tags: android

Делаю расписание, первоначально планировал подготавливать фрагмент(заполнять поля нужными данными)  и и через .add добавлять в скролл вью, но потом понял ,что надо создавать до 400 контейнеров(лейаутов) для фрагментов, что мягко говоря не красиво. Не создать же все вью элементы,в джава коде,или делать отделенный метод где будет создаваться все вью элементы на 1 день и потом его в цикле вызывать?

[image: скриншот приложения]

Comment: Вам однозначно нужно использовать `RecyclerView`. У Вас будет просто список. `RecyclerView` сам позаботится о создании и добавлении вьюшек. Вам нужно будет только предоставлять данные для заполнения.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрел очень удобная вещь